# VS Cross Platform Linux error: cannot optain tty device of remote shell

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I wanted to try the new function on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - Cross Platform for C++ in Linux. I was able to connect with the OrangePi sucessfully, built my project sucessfully, but when I tried to run the code from Visual Studio, I got the error: "cannot optain tty device of remote shell".

The code I am running is an example, which Visual Studio gives you:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#define LED 17

int main(void)
{
wiringPiSetupSys();

pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

while (true)
{
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);  // On
    delay(500); // ms
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);   // Off
    delay(500);
}
return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think applications using Wiring Pi library need to run with `sudo`. [VCLinux can't do this](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/39). Workaround is to run as `root` or go thru the `GPIO utility`.

Comment: I am new to the whole cross-platform thing, but when I configured the SSH connection, I put the login information for the root user. I hoped this would eliminate the possibility of error of this type.

Comment: Ok, if you're running everthing logged in as root and not using sudo then my comments do not apply

Comment: You could also try switching to debugging in `gdb` mode (project properties / debugging page) instead of the default gdbserver mode. Or vice-versa.